# Change comments for every column table

Tags: mysql

I have a Database with hundred of tables and I want to clear all the column comments (or change with `''`)

I try with

```
UPDATE `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
SET TABLE_COMMENT='' 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='mydatabase'
```

but is not possible even with root.

Have any idea???

Comment: Why do you say its not possible? What error do you get?

Comment: Yes even with root user you should not be able to update those information. From the doc `Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database with a USE statement, you can only read the contents of tables, not perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them. ` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: I get this error : Error Code: 1044
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

Comment: You want to change the comment column of the tables or change the comment column of each column of the tables or both?

Comment: Perhaps the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06cee/1) can give you some ideas.

Comment: Cannot access to SQL Fiddle link. Anyway, I want to change the comment column of each column of tables, really want to clean them.

Comment: SQL Fiddle to already be running again, the script maybe help you (check the implications). If the problem persists SQL Fiddle, I will publish the script as a answer. New [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67fd9/1).

Comment: I've seen now. I also think in a solution "building" the SQL Command Lines. I thought in a solution using a query.